# Group homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Determine all group homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Attempt:

Would any group homomorphism be the zero homomorphism or a map $1 \mapsto a$ for any generator $a$ of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$? Are these the only group homomorphisms?

I am struggling to come up with a proof for this. I know the kernel of such a map would be $k\mathbb{Z}$ for some $k$.

Does this help at all?

Comment: This is close! What about the map $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ that sends even numbers to $0$ and odd numbers to $2$, for example? $\Bbb Z$ is a cyclic group, so once you know the image of $1$ under a homomorphism, is there anything else left unknown about the homomorphism? Are there any restrictions on what $1$ could be sent to?

Comment: @GregMartin So $1$ can be sent to anything maybe? Then the homomorphism follows. So just send $1$ to anything, and examine what this does to the rest of the elements in the domain?

Comment: That's right :) Just push that through and you'll have a proof!

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{Z}$ is the free group on 1 element, so homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z} \to G$ correspond naturally to elements of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

> Would any group homomorphism be the zero homomorphism or a map $1 \mapsto a$ for any generator $a$ of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Not quite: $1\mapsto a$ defines a group homomorphism for **any** $a\in\mathbb{Z}_4$, not only a generator. Note that for $a=0$ this also covers the zero homomorphism.

The group of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ is a [free abelian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group), meaning that given any abelian group $G$ and any function $f:\{1\}\to G$ we have that $f$ uniquely extends to a group homomorphism $F:\mathbb{Z}\to G$. This group homomorphism is quite easy to define:

$$F(x):=x\cdot f(1)$$

And vice versa every group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to G$ arises in this fashion. Therefore there is a bijection between $Hom(\mathbb{Z},G)$ and $Func(\{1\},G)$.

In particular there are $4$ group homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}_4$ determined by $4$ possible assignements $1\mapsto a$ for $a\in\mathbb{Z}_4$.